# explorer or application does not resolve dns name but ping does

Tags: windows, networking, windows-8, dns, winpe

I made a win8pe with winbuilder
everything works fine except that explorer does not resolve dns name, but it does work with ip address when try to access network server.

for example, accessing \server1\test returns cannot find network path error, but accessing \10.1.0.1\test works fine

Weird thing is that when ping server1 in command prompt it resolves ip address correctly.

What did I miss here?

many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Late, but just had this same issue, with server names not resolving via Windows Explorer, only IPs, while being pingable. In the process, we took the VM off the domain and tried to rejoin but couldn't.

TCP/IP NetBIOS Helper service wasn't started and set to auto. Fixed getting back on the domain and accessing the file share via explorer.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to clear your DNS Cache using the following command:

```
ipconfig /flushdns
ipconfig /renew
```

If the problem isn't resolved:

1. Go to your network connection properties

   TCP/IP (v4) --> Advanced --> DNS.
2. Check both the check boxes at the end:
3. Register this connection's address in DNS
4. Use this connection's DNS suffix in DNS registration.

Comment: tried that, it did not work, same error